# How to get code coverage in Visual Studio 2012 for mixed managed and native C++ code

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

We are trying to get Code Coverage results in Visual Studio 2012 for a test run that includes C#, managed and native C++.  Our tests are defined in NUnit and we are using the NUnit adapter to be able to run the NUnit tests with coverage in VS2012.  Everything is running and coverage is generated except for the native C++. According to the info I found the coverage should be generated for both the managed and the native code as long as the pdb files are available (and they are).  We are running in debug mode with no optimization enabled.  Any ideas on how to qlso get the coverage results for the native C++?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried all the suggestions here? Troubleshooting code coverage on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159523.aspx

Comment: Yep, that is the one I used as a starting point.

Comment: To isolate problem: 1. First write a small test case in native C++ and calling native C++ code ( without using any testing frameworks )  . if you get code coverage, repeat the same test with the framework.